# bazel run from a running py_binary

Tags: bazel

I've got a py_binary and another runnable target. I want to `bazel run //:the_inner` the second target (which could be a py_binary as well) from the first target `bazel run //:the_outer`

```
py_binary(
  name="the_outer",
  srcs=["the_outer.py"]
)

py_binary(
  name="the_inner",
  srcs=["the_inner.py"]
)
```

A simple

```py
rv = subprocess.run( "bazel run //:the_inner".split(), capture_output=True, text=True)
```

Gives me a error message, telling me I shouldn't do this and tells me the workspace I should have used. At this point I just parse the error message and call the second target again.

```py
workspace = re.search( r"'(\.\w/)+'". rv.stderr ).group(1)
subprocess.run( "bazel run //:the_inner".split(), cwd=workspace)
```

It works, but the solution is extremly awkward. Is there a canonicial way of `bazel run`ning stuff from another `bazel run`, particularly for python?
Solutions I have seen include

- resolving the symlinks in the sandbox and hoping you end up in the workspace
- `find / -name WORKSPACE` and hoping there is only one
- wrapping everything in a shell script and passing `bazel info workspace` as a parameter

No, it shouldn't be done. No don't care - not if there are so many simple workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking was in the docs:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#run

```
subprocess.run( "bazel run //:the_inner".split(), cwd=os.environ.get("BUILD_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY","."))
```

> extra environment variables are also available to the binary:
>
> - BUILD_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY: the root of the workspace where the build was run.
> - BUILD_WORKING_DIRECTORY: the current working directory where Bazel was run from.

Answer (score 1):

The more typical approach is for the "outer" binary to depend on the "inner" binary via "data", and use the python runfiles library to find the inner binary.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/python/runfiles/runfiles.py

For example:

`BUILD`:

```
py_binary(
  name = "a",
  srcs = ["a.py"],
  deps = ["@bazel_tools//tools/python/runfiles:runfiles"],
  data = [":b"],
)

py_binary(
  name = "b",
  srcs = ["b.py"],
)
```

`a.py`:

```
from bazel_tools.tools.python.runfiles import runfiles
import subprocess

r = runfiles.Create()
rv = subprocess.run(r.Rlocation("__main__/b"), capture_output=True, text=True)
print("b says:")
print(rv.stdout)
```

`b.py`:

```
print("hello world")
```

running:

```
$ bazel run a
INFO: Analyzed target //:a (39 packages loaded, 296 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:a up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/a
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.791s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 8 processes: 8 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 8 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 8 total actions
b says:
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't scale if you have a small 'a' and many large 'b' options.

Comment: could you give more details on how it doesn't scale?

Comment: You need prior knowledge of what you are going to so can include it in the data section. You need a target specific launch - you aren't bazel running the target but would have to invoke a shell script different from a python target. Forget running a cc_binary. And while I haven't metered it, I assume that launching a takes longer with a larger data section. Runfiles don't magically appear

Comment: I see -- your question and example were that you had one target and wanted to run another, so it seemed you had particular (fixed) targets in mind. If the "inner" target that you want to run is determined dynamically somehow, then yeah, you wouldn't want to have to list every possible target in the data attribute. Launching the outer binary wouldn't take much longer, runfiles is just a symlink tree (at least on linux/macos), but building it might take longer because bazel would build every dependency in the data attribute.

Comment: Also -- "You need a target specific launch - you aren't bazel running the target but would have to invoke a shell script different from a python target. Forget running a cc_binary" -- in general, it's not whether it's a sh_binary vs py_binary vs cc_binary, but that each binary has different behavior and expects different parameters, right? In general the output of each of those is executable by itself

Comment: I'm not saying your solution is bad. There are places where it is better than what I am using now since your version can do with a single bazel process. However for my use case, I prefer the environment variable.

Comment: Right, I didn't think you were saying that, just trying to fully understand the constraints :)